# Problem installing bokeh: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

As I wasn't able to update bokeh version 0.12.7, I removed the package with `conda remove bokeh`. I then installed the new bokeh version 1.0.4 with `conda install -c bokeh bokeh`. However, I got the error message **[WinError 126] The specified module could not be found**. The strange thing was that I could see these folders and files

- `bokeh-1.0.4-py37_0`,  `packaging-19.0-py37_0`, 
  `yaml-0.1.7-hc54c509_2`, `bokeh-1.0.4-py37_0.tar`, 
  `packaging-19.0-py37_0.tar`,  `yaml-0.1.7-hc54c509_2.tar`

in this directory *D:\Users\jng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs*.

I googled for the solution of *[WinError 126] The specified module could not be found* but no avail.

Could someone please explain what the message mean and advise how I can resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

**Output when trying to install bokeh**

```
(base) D:\Users\jng>conda install -c bokeh bokeh
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: D:\Users\jng09\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - bokeh


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    bokeh-1.4.0                |             py_0        16.8 MB  bokeh
    futures-compat-1.0         |            py3_0          313 B  https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        16.8 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  bokeh              bokeh/noarch::bokeh-1.4.0-py_0
  futures-compat     pkgs/free/noarch::futures-compat-1.0-py3_0
  packaging          pkgs/free/win-64::packaging-16.8-py36_0
  yaml               pkgs/main/win-64::yaml-0.1.7-hc54c509_2


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
bokeh-1.4.0          | 16.8 MB   |                                                              |   0%
futures-compat-1.0   | 313 B     |                                                              |   0%

[WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
[WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

(base) D:\Users\jng>pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/bokeh/simple bokeh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\jng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 3, in <module> import pip
  File "D:\Users\jng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 26, in <module> from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "D:\Users\jng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module> from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "D:\Users\jng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3018, in <module> @_call_aside
  File "D:\Users\jng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3004, in _call_aside f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Users\jng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3046, in _initialize_master_working_set dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "D:\Users\jng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2578, in activate declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "D:\Users\jng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2152, in declare_namespace_handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "D:\Users\jng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2092, in _handle_ns_rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "D:\Users\jng\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2121, in _rebuild_mod_path orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: What happens if you install from defaults rather than the `bokeh` channel? What about if you creat a new separate conda environment instead of installing into base?

Comment: You might also try updating conda itself.

Comment: @bigreddot, I did update conda to 4.8.2. Could you please elaborate what you meant by installing from defaults? Thinking I have screwed up my conda environment (by removing bokeh 0.12.7), I tried to revert to the previous revision with `conda install --revision 20`  but got a *ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)*. I then ran this command `conda install bokeh` and lo and behold it did install bokeh (but only version 0.12.7). I then ran `conda update bokeh` but got a warning of 10 possible package resolutions and *WinError 126] The specified module could not be found*

Comment: To install from defaults, don't add the `-c bokeh` that you have. That specifies the 'bokeh' channel on anaconda.org, rather than the main default channel. In any case, these are all conda issues, and it seems like your environment might be borked. One of the nice things about Anaconda is that it is self-contained in one user directory. I would just blow it all away, and start fresh. And in the future, use conda environments rather than install into base (then you would only need to delete/re-create a single env, not the whole install)

Comment: Thanks, @bigreddot. Good idea about using single environment for efficient delete/re-create.